# Why Intellij console shows confusion logs when starting project with spring-boot?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, logback

My springboot project encoding is UTF-8, used Logback to record logs.

Intellij idea shows confusion logs on the console when I running my project with maven goal `spring-boot:run`, and I have setted the encoding to UTF-8 everywhere as far as I know.

```
public static long ipToDecimal(String ipAddress) {
    InetAddress inetAddress;
    try {
        inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        return new BigInteger(1, inetAddress.getAddress()).longValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("IP转化成数字异常：" + ipAddress, e);
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

It works fine in Eclipse, but failed in Intellij Idea.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also defined the encoding UTF-8 for Logback.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: The fact that you are setting file encoding doesn't mean your console windows necessarily is switched to UTF-8. Also setting this doesn't mean logback is actually logging in utf8 (you have to specify the charset if you don't use the default from Spring Boot).

Comment: And please don't post code as images, post them as code with the proper tags and styling...

Comment: @M.Deinum See my latest question

Comment: No you haven't defined UTF8 for logback... You have defined the file encoding... You have to set the `charset` on your configured `appender` s. (Also I suggest using the Spring Boot default and ditch your custom logback.xml, you can set log levels through the `application.properties` and if you really want your own `logback.xml` at least include the `base.xml` from Spring Boot).

Comment: @M.Deinum I think it's not the problem of Logback, I tried in Ecipse, it works perfectly..

Comment: @JohnChou If you try a simple hello world application writing the same characters in the console, does it display it correctly?

Comment: @M.Deinum It's not correct but also correct in Eclipse..

Comment: If you don't specify the charset it might or might not work in certain IDEs. If you don't want to, however I s strongly suggest configuring the charset else you are basically bound to the platform default...